# How to Set BroadcastReceiver Permissions (Security)

Tags: android, security, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-permissions

So I have 2 apps - A and B.

In A i have a BroadcastReceiver. In the `receiver` tag (manifest file) I specify an `android:permission` string (let's say `com.example.app.SEND`). Now B cannot send broadcasts to A anymore. Makes sense!

So what do I have to do in order for B to send broadcasts to A ? In B's manifest, I specified `uses-permission` tag with `android:name` set to the same string (`com.example.app.SEND`) as the receiver's `android:permission` but still the broadcasts won't go from B to A.

What am I doing wrong ? Or is there something else that needs to be done ?

-- Update --

Here's my app A's receiver tag:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.app.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.example.BReceiver.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.BReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And here's the `uses-permission` tag from my B's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.pycitup.BReceiver.SEND" />
```

Comment: As far as i know Broadcast works on actions not on permissions but yeah you might have to add permissions if you are using any action which requires permissions.

Comment: I'm referring to the [Security](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security) section here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I'd to set a custom permission for the same string like this in B's manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.pycitup.BReceiver.SEND" />
```

Was quite straight-forward and simple. Just required a bit of reading across the web.

Answer (score 0):

From B create an intent and set the action to your broadcast receivers name.

```
Intent myintentB=new Intent();
myintentB.setAction("com.example.app.SEND");
sendBroadcast(myintentB);
```

This should technically hit your receiver.

Comment: I think you're talking about actions, whereas I'm trying to understand how to impose permissions. What I'm referring to is the [Security](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security) section here.

Comment: Permissions are required only for the receiver to know what it can handle.As far as the functionality goes ,without setting the action ,the Broadcast receiver is never in picture.

Comment: Basically I want to impose certain restriction based on the security guide where not all apps can access the receiver. I've updated the question too.